# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBlob' of undefined" when trying to get two different images and insert them into a document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I have a Google Apps Script that automatically extracts data from a Google Sheet and inserts it into a pre specified template.  The data is found using unique tagNumbers/identifiers.

The data being extracted includes 3 signatures.  I can only extract one of these signatures before I encounter the aforementioned error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBlob' of undefined`.

This code is being used in two different functions, using all the same variables and names.  I have tried changing variable names but this has resulted in the same `TypeError`.

The spreadsheet can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14nrRMW-XnoqVLOv87Rf0ufPDGQ0iwfFLA5HigeqhkCg/edit?usp=sharing).

The script is [here](https://script.google.com/d/1TnsVCjlNuuqLdZEKiypSBMw-ddLr0aIR42OQs2WV_W8AErg2ipv8BsQO/edit?usp=sharing).

And the document template being filled is [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1MaCMLoqj1cnA-GjQT3EZdoGfCsybRZ2JcL5Yi-J1p8U/edit?usp=sharing).

Here is the code.

```
function electInstallSignature(row, body){
  var signature = row[17];
  var sign = signature.substring(signature.indexOf("/") + 1);
  var sigFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("16C0DR-R5rJ4f5_2T1f-ZZIxoXQPKvh5C");
  var files = sigFolder.getFilesByName(sign);
  var n = 0;
  var file;
  while(files.hasNext()){
    file = files.next();
    n++;
  } if(n>1){
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('there is more than one file with this name' + sign);
  }
  var sigElectInstaller = "%SIGNELECTINSTALL%";
  var targetRange = body.findText(sigElectInstaller); // Finding the range we need to focus on
  var paragraph = targetRange.getElement().getParent().asParagraph(); // Getting the Paragraph of the target
  paragraph.insertInlineImage(1, file.getBlob());// As there are only one element in this case you want to  insert at index 1 so it will appear after the text // Notice the .getBlob()
  paragraph.replaceText(sigElectInstaller, ""); // Remove the placeholder
}

function commEngineerSignature(row, body){
  var signature = row[35];
  var sign = signature.substring(signature.indexOf("/") + 1);
  var sigFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("16C0DR-R5rJ4f5_2T1f-ZZIxoXQPKvh5C");
  var files = sigFolder.getFilesByName(sign);
  var n = 0;
  var file;
  while(files.hasNext()){
    file = files.next();
    n++;
  } if(n>1){
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('there is more than one file with this name' + sign);
  }
  var sigCommEngineer = "%SFCE%";
  var targetRange = body.findText(sigCommEngineer); // Finding the range we need to focus on
  var paragraph = targetRange.getElement().getParent().asParagraph(); // Getting the Paragraph of the target
  paragraph.insertInlineImage(1, file.getBlob());// As there are only one element in this case you want to  insert at index 1 so it will appear after the text // Notice the .getBlob()
  paragraph.replaceText(sigCommEngineer, ""); // Remove the placeholder
}
```

As you can see, the code is the exact same in both functions, but only works in the `electInstallSignature(row, body)` function.

Below you can find where the `row` and `body` parameters are declared.

```
function chooseRowMethodI(templateId, rowNumber){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = dataRange.getValues();
  var data = sheet.getRange(2, 2, 10, 41).getValues();//starting with row 2 and column 1 as our upper-left most column, get values from cells from 1 row down, and 15 columns along - hence (2,1,1,15)
  var docTitle = sheet.getRange(2, 2, 10, 1).getValues();//this is grabbing the data in field B2
  var docTitleTagNumber = sheet.getRange(2, 5, 11, 1).getValues();
  var today = new Date();
  var dd = today.getDate();
  var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
  today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;

  for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++){
      if(values[i][j] == response){
        Logger.log(i);
        var row = data[rowNumber];
        var docId = DriveApp.getFileById(templateId).makeCopy().getId();  
        var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docId);
        var body = doc.getActiveSection();
        //**************************  All Instruments data in here**********************
        instrumentDetails(body, row);
        electInstallSignature(row, body);
        commEngineerSignature(row, body);

        doc.saveAndClose();
        var file = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId());
        var newFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1Jylk3uO_WU0ClLQdm9y-mwRfHxlh2Ovn");
        newFolder.addFile(file); 
        var newDocTitle = docTitle[i - 1][0];
        var newDocTagNumber = docTitleTagNumber[i - 1][0];
        doc.setName(newDocTitle + " " + newDocTagNumber + " " + today);
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

Should it be required, I have included the function where everything is run from (note that any ui and user input code is tabbed out to avoid having to navigate back to the spreadsheet every time the code is run).

```
var response = "FT101";

function chooseRow(){
//  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.
//  var result = ui.prompt('Please enter the Tag number of the row you wish to print.', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
//  
//  // Process the user's response.
//  var button = result.getSelectedButton();
//  response = result.getResponseText();
//  if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
//    // User clicked "OK".
//    ui.alert('Your tag number is' + response + '.');
//  } else if (button == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
//    // User clicked X in the title bar.
//    ui.alert('You closed the dialog.');
//    return 'the end';
//  }

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = dataRange.getValues();
  var category = sheet.getRange(2, 3, 11, 1).getValues();//Needs to be verified to ensure correct cell is chosen by script
  var tags = sheet.getRange(2, 5, 11, 1).getValues();//Needs to be verified to ensure correct cell is chosen by script

  for(var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++){
    if(tags[i][0] == response && category[i][0] == "Instrument"){
      var templateId = "1N3o951ECS5CAVGE6UgqBiCPC7H7LiJbL7Cd59G1xTnA";
      chooseRowMethodI(templateId, i);
      return "";
    } else if(tags[i][0] == response && category[i][0] == "Motor" || tags[i][0] == response && category[i][0] == "Valve"){
      var templateId = "1cSPD23qFd-34-IIr5eJ5a5OgHp9YR6xav9T28Y4Msec";
      chooseRowMethodMV(templateId, i);
      return "";
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This errors `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBlob' of undefined` means that the `object` you are trying to `getBlob` from it does not have any blob data.

The only difference with the frist function and the second one is the first line:  `row[17]` instead of `row[35]` this means the following:

```js
  var signature = row[17];
  var sign = signature.substring(signature.indexOf("/") + 1);
  var sigFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("16C0DR-R5rJ4f5_2T1f-ZZIxoXQPKvh5C");
  var files = sigFolder.getFilesByName(sign);
  var n = 0;
  var file;
  while(files.hasNext()){
    file = files.next();
    n++;
  } if(n>1){
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('there is more than one file with this name' + sign);
  }
```

So, you are probably never accessing to the while loop:

`while(files.hasNext())`

because `var files = sigFolder.getFilesByName(sign);` never had a next, and thus, as `file` is not initialized, it is `undefined`.

---

In summary, the error you are getting is:

`file` is `undefined`

This means that you never assigned anything on this variable, which only happens if you never accessed the while, which only happens if `files` never had a next.

Which happens because there aren't any files at all there, this means that there isn't any file with the name `sign` on the `sigFolder`. Or that the `row[17]` does not contain any substantial information about the filename you want to access.

So, check this.

Also, take into account the following documentation about iterators like the one you are handling on `files`:

When you do `files.next()` you are accesing the first element of the iterator:

[File iterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator)

General documentation on JavaScript iterators:

[Iterators and generators on Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators)

Comment: Thanks for the help Yuri.  It was a simple stupid mistake of mine.  I had the incorrect row selected which is why it was undefined.